# how to re-enable first time setup at next boot?

Tags: android, cyanogenmod

A friend gave me his new nexus to install CM11 and a few applications.

To install those applications i created a bogus Google account, downloaded them from the store, configured and then removed my account.

now i want to give the phone back in a way that when it is powered on, it shows the create new account/enable Wifi/etc wizard.

I already tried wiping out data from "one time setup" system application, but that did nothing. Any other ideas?

Comment: This answer probably doesn't belong on StackOverflow as it doesn't pertain to programming but is more of a question about android (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). There's an android StackExchange site that would probably be a better fit for this type of question. http://android.stackexchange.com/

Comment: i was almost sure i was typing there :) must have clicked on a notification and forgot to go back ... will close here and move there. thanks Edit: silly system wont allow me to close as off-topic to the android site, only some other random ones. sigh...

Comment: moved to http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/79609/how-to-re-enable-first-time-setup-at-next-boot